# Remotely use SSH key authentication (3

Tags: ssh, key-authentication, remote-control

I have a VM using ubuntu 14.04. running on a windows. If I use the terminal on the VM desktop, I can connect to my servers without passwords using registered SSH Keys.

When I connect to the VM from my windows using a ssh client, I cannot log in the server without password.

```
Linux(VM) ---> Server                     |  Authentication with SSH keys works

SSH session ---> Linux(VM) ---> Server    | Ask for the server password.
```

How can it use the SSH key registered in the VM when I am remotely connected?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which client you are using, but for some the default settings is to forward SSH agent requests and to ignore the middle-man's key(s).  Look in your documentation to disable "agent forwarding", in ssh(1) that is the `-a` option and the `ForwardAgent` configuration value.

Comment: I tried with Putty and SmarTTY. Looking into that.